# Is there any analogue of JsonFormat in Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

My question is really small:

I like Gson a bit more then fastrxml.jackson. One possible feature that I would like to see in Gson is this:

```
//some code
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private Date endDate;
//some code
```

only way to do same thing in Gson that I found is:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
```

I think that annotations are better understandable then above initialization.
Is there any way to annotate or to make some property so that code

```
gson.fromJson("\"{\\\"Id\\\": 703,\\\"StartDate\\\": \\\"2019-10-01T00:00:00\\\"," +
    " \\\"EndDate\\\": \\\"2019-10-25T00:00:00\\\",\\\"Title\\\": \\\"exmample title\\\"}\"",
  MyObj.class)
```

would produce object of class MyObj:

```
public class MyObj{
    @SerializedName("Id")
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("StartDate")
    //analogue of JsonFormat????
    private Date startDate;
    @SerializedName("EndDate")
    //analogue of JsonFormat????
    private Date endDate;
    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String title;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deserialise `JSON` to `POJO` `Gson` uses `com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` class which is marked as `final`. To handle extra annotation you would have to implement something similar plus create new annotation and handle it inside deserialisation logic. Right now, you can implement your custom `com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer` which allows to parse given date.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        MyObj myObj = gson.fromJson(
                "{\"Id\": 703,\"StartDate\": \"2019-10-01T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\": \"2019-10-25T00:00:00\",\"Title\": \"exmample title\"}",
                MyObj.class);
        System.out.println(myObj);
    }
}

class IsoDateTimeJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

        return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}

class MyObj {

    @SerializedName("Id")
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("StartDate")
    @JsonAdapter(IsoDateTimeJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Date startDate;

    @SerializedName("EndDate")
    @JsonAdapter(IsoDateTimeJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Date endDate;

    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String title;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
MyObj{id=703, startDate=Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 CEST 2019, endDate=Fri Oct 25 00:00:00 CEST 2019, title='exmample title'}
```